# DocuSign SOAP API - Custom Tab - Optional Text Field

Tags: docusignapi

We are setting up the document to have an **optional** text field. We are using DocuSign SOAP API.

We have added Tab configuration, with anchor string, to specify details of custom Text box. The text box appears in the document, but it's always **mandatory**. Here is the configuration which we setup.

I have gone through various DocuSign support tickets, and community but couldn't find a solution for the same. Please let us know if there is anything missing, or we have a workaround for the same.

I don't see the definition of CustomTabRequiredSpecified in wsdl.

**Snippet**

```
Tab.RecipientID                                       = "1"
Tab.DocumentID                                        = "1"
Tab.Type                                              = "Custom"
Tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTab.XOffset                   = 0
Tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTab.YOffset                   = 0
Tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTab.IgnoreIfNotPresent        = True
Tab.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTab.AnchorTabString           = "AnchorString"
Tab.CustomTabWidth                                    = 100
**Tab.CustomTabRequired                                 = False**
Tab.CustomTabType                                     = "Text"
Tab.TabLabel                                          = "UniqueNameField"
Tab.TemplateRequired                                  = False
Tab.SharedTab                                         = True
Tab.RequireAll                                        = False
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make the text tab optional with these 2 lines of code:

```
Tab.CustomTabRequired = false;
Tab.CustomTabRequiredSpecified = true;
```

Please make sure you are referencing this WSDL: https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?wsdl

Comment: Thank you. I was using SOAP api's and the tool didnt import the wsdl to have CustomTabRequiredSpecified attribute. I had to update it to "always send" the value of CustomTabRequired and it worked. The value "false" was not sent it was defaulted to true.